# What is the query for table 3?

Tags: sql-server, erp

I have extracted these two tables from a SQL Database:

[image: table 1]

**query for table 1:**

```
SELECT POM_DOCNO,
POM_DATE,
SUP_CODE,
POM_CREATEDBY 
FROM SI_PURORDERMASTER
WHERE POM_YEAR = 2012
AND POM_PERIOD = 6
```

[image: table 2]

**query for table 2:**

```
SELECT POM_DOCNO,
ITM_ITEMCODE,
ITM_ITEMDESC,
POD_QTY,
POD_RATE
FROM SI_PURORDERDETAIL
WHERE POM_YEAR = 2012
AND POM_PERIOD = 6
```

[image: table 3]

query to get table 3 ?

I have tried using joins but always end up with wrong result :/
Is there anyway to get table 3 with just table 1 & 2 ?
Both table 1 and 2 have **"POM_DOCNO"** column in common.

Comment: Add the join you tried to your question.

Comment: Help us help you - please share the query you tried and the result you got, and explain why it's wrong.

Comment: SELECT SI_PURORDERMASTER.POM_DOCNO,
SI_PURORDERMASTER.POM_DATE, 
SI_PURORDERMASTER.SUP_CODE, 
SI_PURORDERDETAIL.ITM_ITEMCODE,
SI_PURORDERDETAIL.POD_QTY,
SI_PURORDERDETAIL.POD_RATE, 
SI_PURORDERMASTER.POM_CREATEDBY
FROM SI_PURORDERDETAIL
INNER JOIN SI_PURORDERMASTER
ON SI_PURORDERDETAIL.POM_DOCNO = SI_PURORDERMASTER.POM_DOCNO

Comment: I have actually tried various modified version of above query, but I just dont get it what I am doing wrong. I tried chaning the join type even... but no use, it just doesnt show what I want as table 3. Also the result I got from running the above query is pretty big... like thousands of rows... I dont think I can post those all here...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that;

```
SELECT TOP 5
SIR.POM_DOCNO,
SIR.POM_DATE,
SIR.SUP_CODE,
SIL.ITM_ITEMCODE,
SIL.POD_QTY,
SIL.POD_RATE,
SIR.POM_CREATEDBY 
FROM SI_PURORDERMASTER SIR inner join SI_PURORDERDETAIL SIL ON SIR.POM_DOCNO = SIL.POM_DOCNO
WHERE SIR.POM_YEAR = 2012
AND SIR.POM_PERIOD = 6
```

Also, just use `TOP` to limit results. If you want to specift order you should use `order by`

Comment: thanks for replying and running this query got me the table 3 i want but with additional 147 rows as well... meaning top 5 rows that are in table 3 are showing but with extra random data rows....

Comment: adding top 5 is not showing the correct result now, its showing 5 rows but not the correct ones.... ill try ORDER BY and update

Comment: What is the "correct result" ? What is their specific filter or order rule ?

Comment: the rows shown in table 3... your query before adding TOP 5 was working but with additional random/wrong data (how do i share the image of that in comments?) ,I was getting top rows exact as shown in table 3 but after adding TOP 5 and also ORDER BY ... its showing POM_DOCNO = 0000000036 in all 5 rows... which is not the case if you see the table.

Comment: "the rows shown in table 3" sql doesn't work like that. The records which you want to retrieve should have a logic. What makes the specific that records ? You should provide some details about their filter or order.

Comment: @Hey_its_Me  - Can't understand your logic. do you want that fix table3 data or dynamic data as shown in table3 ??

Comment: I simply just want to merge table 1 and table 2. Using query 1 and query 2 I extracted limited data and not all the data of table 1 and table 2. The main column both tables have in common is "pom_docno".

Comment: Query provided by Rainman solved half my problem. It merged the table and showed the result shown in table 3 but with extra random 142 rows.

Comment: I am basically trying to generate a report. 4 columns are present in table 2, and 1 column is present in table 1 (sup_code). Common columns in between them is pom_docno, pom_year and pom_period.